# Beamer "box" too big when I add more subsubsections

Tags: beamer

I am preparint a presentation in beamer using the theme "beamerthemeshadow". In all slides, next to the superior border, a list appears always with section and subsection name, highlighted depending on the part of the presentation I am. It worked fine, but I observe now, in some part I added 5 subsubsections, and now the "box" (what is the right name for this?) grew a lot, so now it takes half slide! I do not udnerstand this since subsubsections do not appear on this object. Can you tell me how do I solve this?
Thanks

P.D. And how can one shorten the name of the subsections and sections as they appear on this "box"?

Comment: have you already tried things like \subsection[short for toc]{long for slide}?

Comment: @martin H I'd suggest adding that as an answer.

Comment: yes, that works! but my main question is the problem with the box size when having around 8 subsubsectios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In beamer you can use the function of providing short names for the table of contents. This works in regular document classes as well.

In you case using

```
\subsection[short version for toc]{long version}
```

should give a smaller toc-box.

Comment: I still get the same error, although the titles are shorter now

Comment: you should provide a minimal working example. otherwise there is too much guesswork involved

Comment: In that case: \subsubsection[short version for toc]{long version} short version does not appear (I get the long version). \ How could I fix this problem?

Comment: @ConstantineDelisTsardounis I converted your answer, which actually is a question, to a comment.